# Use .NET type for cast before type definition was loaded

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, types, casting

I just wonder if it is possible to use a type for the declaration before the assembly containing the definition is loaded at all.

I have a powershell v5 class that I like to declare neatly.
See below:

```
class MySQL
{

[MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection]
$connection

[MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand]
$_command


static MySQL()
{   
    if(([appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies() | Where {$_ -match "MySql.Data"}) -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Verbose "MySQL assembly has not been loaded yet. Try to load....";

        try
        {
            [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
        }
        catch
        {
            if([MySQL]::getConnectorFromWeb())
            {
                [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("MysqlL.Data, Version=$script:version, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d")

            }
            else
            {
                throw "MySQL connector import failed!"
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return
    }

#different other methods....
}
```

Now this script can't be parsed because the types for the properties do not exist at begin of the script. E.g. [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection] will be available when the static constructor has been called for the first time to import the assembly.

I am not sure if there is a possibility to do it like that. At least in PowerShell that is actually interpreted so even if the script is just "read" at all it won't create my new type "MySql" because it can't parse the properties.

Any idea how I can get rid of this "TypeNotFound" Exception but still using static type definitions like casts? (PowerShell is actually dynamic and does not necessarily require explicit type references)

Addition:
Now I added a method like this:

```
   [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySQLConnection]getConnection()
   {
       return $this.connection
   }
```

and of course this can not be parsed as well, because the type [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySQLConnection] is not known yet. I suppose it is no problem in C# because you will not load assemblies dynamically but declaring all necessary environment with the "using" statements. But this is not possible in PowerShell :(

Comment: You could try `using assembly MySql.Data` on top of your script.

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see I am using PowerShell and no full feature .NET language as C#. There is no using statement in PowerShell as there is not really support for namespaces at all :)

Comment: There is `using` statement in PowerShell v5. currently working forms: `using module`, `using assembly` and `using namespace`.

Comment: Ouh you are right. But sadly this does not do the trick anyway.
Thanks at all for giving me the hint, I was not aware that a using directive is available now :)

Comment: But @PetSerAl
I do not find any clear documentation about the PowerShell using directives except the one below (it is not a documentation at all, just a sample)
https://gist.github.com/guitarrapc/e092ffb40e06fec40216

It seems there is a using type directive as well, but I can't make it working, I think it is something about an assignment, but I am not sure, I just noticed that the script parser allows a "using type" without underlining it as wrong.

Can you tell me where you got that information from please? :)

Comment: There are also `using type` and `using command` but currently there is no way to write them without causing syntax error. One time I dig in PowerShell assemblies with ILSpy, I somehow noticed by [`UsingStatementAst`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.language.usingstatementast.aspx) class. My first thought was: *since when PowerShell have `using` statement*. And I start digging deeper into it. I can not point you to any documentation about that, even MSDN does not have anything at that moment.

Comment: Hi @PetSerAl
Thanks a lot for the information. Sadly I noticed that the new PS Class features are rarely documented yet although the preview was released 13 months ago and the stable one in July :-(
I hope to get a lot of more explanation soon from Microsoft what is possible in the class based concept of PowerShell. I am interested a lot.